# Remove jQuery AJAX timestamp from query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, query-string

How can I remove the jQuery AJAX cache preventer (`_=3452345235`) when dealing with string URLs?

I am writing a global AJAX fail handler and to do this I need to know which URL failed, but everytime I check the URL of the request which failed the jQuery cache query string means all my URLs are different so I need to remove this from the string before doing any more work

So if my URL is (as a string, not `window.location`) is

```
/device/page/?page=2&_=23523452345
```

I want to solely remove the timestamp to be left with

```
/device/page/?page=2
```

Comment: Edited: From the reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, I'd think that setting cache: true (um, it should be true by default) should resolve your issue.

Comment: Ive turned caching off because I want caching off, I just want to remove the appended qs at this point in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis should work for you.

```
var url = '/device/page/?page=2&_=23523452345';

url = url.replace(/&?_=[0-9]*/, '');
```

Regards.

**UPDATE**

The first work for at the end and in the middle of the query string but not at the beginning of the query sting `?_=212115211&page=2`.

This regex works for any location of the `_` param.

```
url = url.replace(/&?_=[0-9]*/, '');
```

Thanks

Comment: Great thanks, how do I make it work for the beginning too? Would `url.replace(/_=[0-9]*/, '');` suffice?

Comment: Use the second regex `url = url.replace(/&?_=[0-9]*/, '');`